# How to handle events in CRDXE through JavaScript in AEM

Tags: jquery, adobe, aem

I want to know how I can write `JavaScript` code that will handle button clicks and other functionality in `AEM`.

I have created two radio buttons through the wizards, by creating items, and want to know how to handle the click events of the buttons. On each radio button selection, I would like to show different forms.

But I am a little bit confused about how to write `JavaScript` code and define `CSS` rules that relate to the node items in `CRDXE`. I would like to get help learning about how to write `JavaScript` code inside `CRDXE`.

Comment: Do you have some code examples of what you have tried?

Comment: I am working on AEM and i went through the code and find coding is done through jsp but i want to know is there any way to add javascript code so that i will handle radio button clicks in AEM .

Comment: Your coworker posted the exact same question regarding multiple radio buttons in the wizard widget. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204874/how-to-create-wizards-in-grante-ui-and-design-it-in-coral-ui-html-in-aem. Voting to close.

Comment: With time you'll realize that CRXDE has nothing to do with the problem that you're trying to solve. It's just a very helpful tool that Day created.